# Got "finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection" error, what is it from?

Tags: android

I try to send back a result using `onActivityResult`. When I `finish()` last activity (by `setResult(RESULT_OK, incomingIntent);` ) it should go to first activity but it's not. An UI is freeze, can't do anything with it except push BACK Button.

In Logcat show this

> **Tag :** IInuputConnectionWrapper
>
> **Text :** finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection

When click back it work again and go to `onActivityResult` on first activity.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

At last I realized that this problem is not involve to with `InuputConnectionWrapper`, but because FB Session.